# In Java, can Class.forName ever return null?

Tags: java, classloader

In Java, can Class.forName ever return null, or will it always throw a ClassNotFoundException or NoClassDefFoundError if the class can't be located?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Java Docs says it will throw ClassNotFoundException if the class cannot be found so I'd say it never returns null.

Comment: What if you're using a custom classloader?

Comment: Then the custom classloader is breaking the contract.  You'll have to decide if you want to code for that contingency.  Similarly if you're using an AOP runtime top rewrite existing classes, like the classloader.  :-)

Comment: @Darron: Which contract are you referring to?

Comment: @Hemal on Darron: To return ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: Don't know what I am missing. Are you referring to the fact that `Class.forName throws CNFE`? But that does not mean it cannot return null, or that it cannot throw other unchecked exceptions.

Answer (score 5):

Since null is not mentioned anywhere in the documentation for this method and because there doesn't seem to be any situation in which it would make sense for the method to return null instead of throwing an exception, I think it's pretty safe to assume that it never returns null.

It won't throw a NoClassDefFoundError, but it may throw ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: Why won't it throw a NCDFError?

Comment: It already throws ClassNotFoundException, it would be confusing if it used both.  NoClassDefFoundError is thrown by the VM when it can't find a class in the course of its normal operations.  ClassNotFoundException is thrown when a class cannot be found by code that uses reflection.

Comment: That's not quite true. Class.forName does throw NCDFE, see my response below.

Comment: @Hermal: No it doesn't; the JVM throws it in your example trying to resolve a class from a "normal" reference (non reflected); it just happens to percolate through Class.forName().  Any method can see a NCDFError pass through it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the default class loader, surely you will receive no nulls. But, as jdigital says, you may be subject to any number of custom classloaders depending on what security model or other type of proxy loader that you may be using (intentionally or otherwise).

Heck, even forName can take a ClassLoader as a parameter... :)

Piko

Comment: Well if you're using a "bad" custom class loader, you can get a Cow for that matter!! :)

Comment: This answer would only be accurate for a class loader which breaks it's documented contract - I wouldn't bother coding for that.

Answer (score -2):

@Dan Dyer is wrong, Class.forName *can* throw `NoClassDefFoundError`, if the class it is trying gets a ClassNotFoundException error in its static initialiazer. The following is unte

```
class Outer {
  public static final void main(final String[] args) throws Exception{
    Class.forName("Inner");
  }
}
```

If you compile and run this in a directory with no other file you get `ClassNotFoundException: Inner`

Now add the following to in the same directory, compile everything and `java Outer` once to see it runs ok.

```
class Inner {
  static Inner2 _i2 = new Inner2();
}

class Inner2 {}
```

Finally, delete Inner2.class and rerun Outer, you *will* get `NoClassDefFoundError: Inner2`, `caused by ClassNotFoundException: Inner2`

Comment: No it doesn't; the JVM throws it in your example trying to resolve a class from a "normal" reference (non reflected); it just happens to percolate through Class.forName(). Any method can see a NCDFError pass through it.

Comment: Hmmm. Yes, I see what you are saying. It's like saying Class.forName throws NPE or OOME, because the class to be loaded throws it in its clinit.

Comment: "@Dan Dyer is wrong" is not a great way to answer a question from Phil.

Comment: Yes, it should have been a comment to Dan's answer. But I wanted to formatted code so I used a separate entry. Of course, I was wrong in saying Dan is wrong. Look at the benefit: as bonus, I also got a few downvotes :-)