# Differences between NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundException?

Tags: java, classloader

NoClassDefFoundError extends LinkageError which in turns extends Error.

Javadoc for Error class states:

> An `Error` is a subclass of `Throwable` 
>     that indicates serious problems that a reasonable application 
>     should not try to catch.

Class loading methods like `Class.forName()` only declares `ClassNotFoundException` in throws clause. Which, in addition to above description of `Error` means that we should not be usually catching the `NoClassDefFoundError` when loading classes with `Class.forName()` etc.

**My question is what are the conditions in which `NoClassDefFoundError` is thrown instead of `ClassNotFoundException`?**

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457863/what-is-the-difference-between-noclassdeffounderror-and-classnotfoundexception

Comment: I also found a related discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430089/in-java-can-class-forname-ever-return-null/430092#430092

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ClassNotFoundException` is more likely to be thrown (to *your* code) in situations where you're manually loading classes - precisely for things like `Class.forName()`. These names may come from user input, for example.

`NoClassDefFoundError` will occur when a class file itself refers to a class that then can't be found. The class *was* present at some time, but now isn't - this isn't just a bug in the code that's trying to do reflection, it's a deployment mistake of not making all the required classes available. As far as I can tell a `NoClassDefFoundError` will usually or possibly always *wrap* a `ClassNotFoundException` - but the point is that this isn't something *your* code is meant to guard against, as it indicates an environment which is probably too broken to recover from.

At least, that's my understanding :)

Comment: There's another much higher rated question for this, with higher rated answers, but I felt that this answer explained it better and gave information lacking from the others.  (Such as the observation that NoClassDefFoundError appears to always wrap ClassNotFoundException, which clears up a lot for me about the intent of these two classes.)

Comment: @Jon Can you give a practical example of when class names come from user input?

Comment: @Geek: Well you *could* ask a user to entry a class name, then use `Class.forName` to find that class.

Comment: @JonSkeet Is this usual in Java EE applications?  I am looking for a more practical example.

Comment: @Geek: No, it's not very common. It was only *one* source of text data. Another might be an XML configuration file for Dependency Injection, e.g. a Spring config file.

Comment: @JonSkeet The Spring example make more sense. Thanks for the clarification and ofcourse +1.

Answer (score 0):

NoClassDefFoundError occures at runtime because compiler not able to find .class file.