# Class.forName returning null

Tags: java, classloader

I've seen a post regarding whether or not Class.forName can return null [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430089/in-java-can-class-forname-ever-return-null) and everyone seems to think it can't (or wont).  However, it is returning null for me with this code:

```
  public void init() {
    File binDriectory = new File("./bin/dft");
    String[] files = binDriectory.list();
    for (String file : files) {
      if (file.endsWith(".class")) {
        if (file.indexOf("DataReader") > 0) {
          //strip off the ".class"
          String className = file.substring(0, file.indexOf(".class"));

          try {
            //load the class
            Class readerclass = Class.forName("dft." + className);
            //get the file extension of the file type this class deals with

            /* NullPointerException thrown here in call to getMthod() */

            Method getExtensionMethod = readerClass.getMethod("getFileExtension", null);
            String extension = (String) getExtensionMethod.invoke(readerClass.newInstance(), null);
            //add the extension and class to the class map
            classMap.put(extension, readerClass);
            //add the extension to the list of reader file extensions
            readerExtensions.add(extension);
          }
          catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("**WARNING: class not found: dft." + className);
            continue;
          }
          catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            System.err.println("**WARNING: class dft." + className + " does "
                               + "not contain a getFileExtension() method.");
            continue;
          }
          catch (InstantiationException e) {
            System.err.println("**WARNING: could not create an instance of "
                               + "class dft." + className);
            continue;
          }
          /* with Java 7, these next two catch blocks can be combined (and they
             should) */
          catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            System.err.println("**WARNING: could not invoke getFileExtension()"
                               + " method from class dft." + className);
            continue;
          }
          catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            System.err.println("**WARNING: could not invoke getFileExtension()"
                + " method from class dft." + className);
            continue;
          }

          System.out.println(className);
        }
        else if (file.indexOf("DataWriter") > 0) {
          System.out.println(file);
        } 
      }
    }
  }
```

ClassNotFoundException is NOT thrown, but the result of forName() is null.  The documentation says nothing about returning null.

Does anyone have any clue as to why this is happening?  I tested the call of forName() in another project that doesn't use a package name (the code above is in a package named "dft"), and that one worked fine.  I'm thinking that has something to do with it.  The classpath is fine as well--the .class files are in ...bin/dft and the classpath contains .../bin.  I even tried adding the .../bin/dft directory explicitly in the classpath just in case, and it still returns null.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are assigning the value returned by `forName` to

`readerclass`    (lowercase C)

but calling `getMethod` from

`readerClass`    (uppercase C)

which probably is an uninitialized field.

*Java is case-sensitive.*

Comment: you caught him! (+1) If his code really compiles he has yet another variable readerClass on class level. But this variable is never initialized.

Comment: Yep, that was it.  Wow, that is embarrassing.  Nice catch!  Thanks for the debug!

Comment: @Tyler - no problem. This kind of error normally is very hard to find in the **own** code - you are so *used* to the code, that you don't see these small details.

Comment: Normally I would say this question should be closed since the issue is caused by a simple typo unlikely to impact anyone else, except the same freaking thing happened to me. I'm using Groovy (so the code didn't get run through a compiler), but somehow I misspelled my `cl` variable as `c1` and didn't notice it until I read this post. Making the typo more brutal than usual is how similar my font renders `l` (lowercase L) and `1` (digit one). There's just the slightest bend on the hat of the `1` that isn't present on `l`. SO font has the same issue.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare happened to me when using punched cards... `DO 1 = 1, 10` (or similar) It toke me over one week to find that (first 1 should be an i)!

Answer (score 3):

If the class *is in your project's classpath* (even if it's one of the classes of your current project that's already compiled) `Class.forName(...)` should work.

The only way Class.forName can throw NullPointerException is if the class you're trying to load has a static initialized that it itself throws NPE for some reason.